# Como acessar a View que disparou um dos eventos de um TextWatcher?

Tags: android, eventos, listener, edittext

## Explicação:

Tenho uma aplicação comum onde há vários componentes `EditText`, onde eu atribuo-os um handler que  seria este aqui:

```java
TextWatcher handler = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        oldText = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //v.setText("afterTextChanged");
    }
};
```

Está funcionando ok, e o debugger entra certinho, os eventos são disparados, porém eu gostaria de ter acesso a View que está disparando os eventos para ter acesso ao método `.setText()`.

## Pergunta:

Como fazer para acessar a `View` que disparou um evento do handler `TextWatcher`?

#### Exatamente da mesma forma do `v` do evento *onClick*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquilo que você procura é o valor `s` passado para a função. Se você alterar `s` o `TextView` mostrará essa alteração.

Tenha atenção que, qualquer alteração que você fizer a `s`, o método `afterTextChanged` irá ser chamar novamente, o que irá provocar um *loop* infinito.

**Fonte** [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29)

Comment: Mas eu devo alterar o `s` de que forma? `s = "aa"` ?

Comment: Sim. Internamente a classe TextView usa um `Editable`(ou algo que herde de `Editable`) para guardar o seu valor. Isso é passado para o método `afterTextChanged`. Quando você invoca `getText` o que retorna é um `Editable`